# Search Replace extended in a html file

Tags: notepad++, search, regex, find-and-replace

i have a little question. I have a big html file and want to replace lots of things inside a lot of times. The only problem i cant solve is a replace with a variable.

Example:

```
<image src="start_files\0002.jpg" style="width:216pt; height:162">
```

should be transformed in

```
<a href="start_files\0002.jpg" target="_blank"><image src="start_files\0002.jpg" style="width:216pt; height:162"></a>
```

do you have an idea how to do it?

I have a windows system with Notepad2 and Notepad++ and i could install a new tool if needed. (like Windows SED). The best solution would be a batch solution where I can add other transformations.

Hope you have got good ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has regular expression search & replace support. You just need to craft a regex to meet your conditions.

Comment: But can i reference parts of the search in the replace?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a perl script (to use with grep e.g.):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$src='<image src="start_files\\0002.jpg" style="width:216pt; height:162">';
$xp1='(<)';     
$xp2='(image)'; 
$xp3='( )';
$xp4='(src)';
$xp5='(=)';
$xp6='(".*?")';
$xp7='( )';
$xp8='(style)';
$xp9='(=)';
$xp10='(".*?")';
$xp11='(>)';
$xp=$xp1.$xp2.$xp3.$xp4.$xp5.$xp6.$xp7.$xp8.$xp9.$xp10.$xp11;
if ($src =~ m/$xp/is)
{
        $outi="<a href="."$6"." target=\"_blank\"> "."$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11 \n";
    print $outi;    
}
```